# Algorithm to find max no. of nodes that can be visited

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given an undirected non-weighted graph edges.
`'1#2', '2#3', '1#11', '3#11', '4#11', '4#5', '5#6', '5#7', '6#7', '4#12', '8#12', '9#12', '8#10', '9#10', '8#9'`
where for example node 1 and node 2 is having a direct edge

now the question is, which algorithm can be used to find the maximum no. of nodes that can be visited (starting from any node), visiting a node atmost once and no traversing back by any edge

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the [Longest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) and is known to be NP-hard.

Hence there is no known polynomial time algorithm to answer your problem, and unless P=NP there are no such algorithm.

So to answer your question you may as well enumerate all the possible path visiting at most once each vertex and find the longest.